# Hints in TrueType fonts

Tags: fonts, truetype

We are using (special) TrueType fonts to render (linear) barcodes into PDF files.

Is there a way to use hinting (in the font file) to force that the font can only be scaled onto full pixel boundaries (and that lines and spaces are always on pixel boundaries)?

The idea would be to make sure that the effective font size is limited to values, with produce integer line widths (or use the next smaller value).

Any idea about a tool that can achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

There are tools that can edit TrueType hints (properly, "instructions") to do what you wish. FontForge allows the editing of hints and there are other commercial tools available as well. If you are not already familiar with the TrueType language, you should be prepared for a fairly challenging undertaking.

Reference material: https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM03/Chap3.html

However: you should be aware that hints in TrueType fonts aren't always used (depending on the rendering environment). For example, in modern Apple operating systems, TrueType hints are ignored. Other systems such as Windows with ClearType partially ignore some kinds of hints. There are likely other cases, too. Thus, unless you can be sure of the conditions in the entire process end-to-end, your efforts may be a waste of time.

Comment: Is there another way to solve my problem (if I don't know the output device and it's resolution at PDF generation time)? The hint logic should be simple (and identical for all characters). Where can I find docs and sample hinting code?

Comment: There may be another way, but I'm not sure what it is. If you don't know or can't control the output device, you can't guarantee that your hints will be used (no matter how simple). I've edited my answer to include a link to the Apple TrueType Reference Manual section about instructing TrueType fonts.